# Lua NGINX How to get only one value from json POST body

Tags: nginx, lua, lua-table, openresty

Hello I have lua nginx and I'm having request body

My POST body is this :

```
{
    "param1": "1033893",
    "param2": "337483",
    "param3": "test",
    
}
```

I want to cut only **param2** and make it a variable, then match it with a file which it's having lines that contain numbers like this.

If it's found then I should call another command

**Update 1 :**

I'm using

```
local check_body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
```

**Update 2:**

In bash I'm using this to cut the part and value of param2

```
echo $CURL_post_request | cut -d\| -f 1| grep -m1  -oP '\s*"param2"\s*:\s*\K[^,]+'| tr -d '"'| tr -d '}'
```

But in lua I'm not sure how to cut and put as variable?

Comment: Don't use patterns / RegEx to extract data from JSON. Instead, use a proper JSON parser, then extract the fields you need.

Comment: @LMD can you give me a proper example?

Comment: Look into e.g. [json.lua](https://github.com/rxi/json.lua/). It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Hello @LMD thanks very much, I'm a little beginner with Lua, so I'm getting the following encode the response

` "{\r\n    \"param1\": \"1033893\",\r\n    \"param2\": \"337483\",\r\n    \"param3\": \"test\",\r\n    \"param4\": \"542722\",\r\n    \"param5\": 5,\r\n    \"param6\": {\r\n        \"status\": \"Success\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"resultData\": null\r\n}" `

But if I use it to decode

I get this in my error log 
` bad argument #1 to 'say' (non-array table found) `

Also what do you prefer for cutting param2 value?

Comment: Hi again @LMD I'm using 

  ` json = require "json"
   local json_parse = json.encode(check_body)
   local param2_cut = json_parse.param2
   ngx.say(iccid_cut) `

Comment: you need to use `json.decode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using another module http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home

First i'm doing adding entry to nginx.conf

```
lua_package_path "/usr/local/openresty/lualib/?.lua;;";


  json = require "dkjson"
   local json_parse = json.decode(check_body)
   local iccid_cut = json_parse.param2
```